# aspnetcore routing to controller action with custom route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controller "ServicesController" with the action "Edit" taking one string parameter "serviceId".

This controller has a route applied as shown and works as expected.

```
[Route("Services/Edit/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditService(string id)
{
    Service s = await _servicesService.GetService(id);
    return View("EditService", s);
}
```

When I try to redirect to this route from another action I can only get the value to show as a query

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = s.Id });
// redirects to /Services/Edit?id=exampleid
```

I've searched a few related answers where people have asked the same question but the solutions suggested don't work for me, presuming it's because I have the route decoration on my action maybe?

Ive also tried the below but that redirects to the calling action with the id

```
[Route("Services/Foo/{serviceId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Foo(string serviceId)
{
    // redirects to /Services/Foo/exampleid
    return RedirectToRoute("Edit", serviceId);
}
```

Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: Does putting `[FromRoute]` in front of the parameter work? `EditService([FromRoute] string id)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First argument of `RedirectToAction` is `actionName`, it is the name of the method, in our case it should be `EditService`. Here is a link to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Controller_RedirectToAction_System_String_System_Object_). So, I believe the correct version should be like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("EditService", new { id = s.Id });
```

It also has an overloaded version `RedirectToAction(string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues)`, it allows to specify controller in case you are redirecting not inside the same controller.

Regarding `RedirectToRoute`, it accepts a name of the route, for that we need to set the name for our `EditService(string id)` action like this:

```
[Route("Services/Edit/{id}", Name = "MyEditServiceRoute")]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditService(string id)
{
    ...
}

...

{
    ...
    return RedirectToRoute("MyEditServiceRoute", serviceId);
}
```

Comment: I knew it would be probably be some silly mistake like that, thanks for your help 

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = s.Id });
```

Try:

```
return EditService( s.Id );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the route an explicit name using the "name" attribute on the Route.

```
[Route("Services/Edit/{id}", Name="EditService")]
```

Then provide that specific name on the redirect:

```
return RedirectToAction("EditService", new { id = s.Id });
```

Comment: And ochzhen beat me by 5 seconds. ;)